# How to convert poly-line contour feature class into heat map displaying heights

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, contour, heat-map

I'm looking for a way to be able to convert contour data (as lines) into a heat map that would display the data warmest at the highest points and coolest at the lowest.

I have access to QGIS, ArcMap (only the Basic license though), DNRGPS and can use freeware.

Comment: Do the contours have a value attribute of some kind? If not, do they have a Z-coordinate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'heat map' in this context. Sounds to me like you just want a particular color ramp applied to the lines based on elevation value. Do you want to display just lines or a continuous surface like a raster or TIN?